# Remove the unwanted text through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a table which I cannot access the HTML code. I want to remove 'Information' and '|' coming before "registration" link. I only want Registration link in the `<td>`. This is what I am trying to do.

```
<script>
    j$(document).ready(function() {
        j$('td.table-text:contains("|")').replaceWith(" ");
    });
</script>
</head>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="Registrants" class="grid">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="">
            <td class="table-text">
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="AutoCheckGuest('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl01_rptRegistrants_ctl00_chkRegistrant', 'Registrants', 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl01_trAddAnother', 'True');" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl01$rptRegistrants$ctl00$chkRegistrant" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl01_rptRegistrants_ctl00_chkRegistrant" class="">
                <input type="hidden" value="75a6c1cd-39bc-4cfd-b220-5a8b2bba1ff9" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl01_rptRegistrants_ctl00_hdnRegistrant" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl01$rptRegistrants$ctl00$hdnRegistrant">
                <input type="hidden" value="3" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl01_rptRegistrants_ctl00_hdnEntityType" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl01$rptRegistrants$ctl00$hdnEntityType">
            </td>
            <td class="table-text">Test Name
                <label class="BodyTextBold1" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl01_rptRegistrants_ctl00_lblPrimaryInvitee" for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl01_rptRegistrants_ctl00_chkRegistrant">(Primary Registrant)</label>
            </td>
            <td class="table-text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl01_rptRegistrants_ctl00_tdRegistrationType">Group Leader&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="table-text"><a href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl01$rptRegistrants$ctl00$btnModifyPersonalInfo&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl01_rptRegistrants_ctl00_btnModifyPersonalInfo" onclick="javascript:return ValidateUnregisterCheckBox('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl01_rptRegistrants_ctl00_chkRegistrant','You cannot modify information for a guest that is about to be unregistered.');">Information</a> | <a href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl01$rptRegistrants$ctl00$btnModifyRegInfo&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl01_rptRegistrants_ctl00_btnModifyRegInfo" onclick="javascript:return ValidateUnregisterCheckBox('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl01_rptRegistrants_ctl00_chkRegistrant','You cannot modify information for a guest that is about to be unregistered.');">Registration</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can traverse to find the last `a` element in the last `td` and replace its contents. Try this:

```
var $td = $('td').last();
var $a = $td.find('a').last();
$td.empty().append($a);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/g6x3t75n/1/)

If you need to achieve this on multiple rows of a table, you can instead use the `:last-child` selector:

```
var $tds = $('tr td:last-child');
var $a = $tds.find('a').last();
$td.empty().append($a);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/g6x3t75n/2/)